# Perl 5.12.3 fails to loop CSV file line by line

Tags: perl, csv

I'm sure someone has an explanation as to what is happening with the following script:

Please note, the file I specify is available and is opening.  I know this because the last line of the file is output when the program is run, but it is only the last line.

Note about the .csv file: it's generated on windows (I'm using OS X 10.7.4 with Perl 5.12.3) and uses `\r` line breaks.  I attempted to tell perl that the line break character was \r at the top of the script but it does not work.  I know they're `\r` as the grep search finds them in a text editor.

The script runs and only prints the last line of the file.  If I plug in a regular expression it will grab the first matching field from the first line and echo it fine, but I cannot iterate over the entire file.

Any clarification is appreciated as I am new to perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;

print "Please enter your filename:";


my ($dataline);
open(INFO,'./expensereport.csv') || die("can't open datafile: $!");

while (my $line = <INFO>)  {
chomp $line;
print $line;


}
print $!;
```

Comment: On windows line break is two characters `\r\n` in that order.

Comment: @n0rd and chomp only removes one of them.  For Windows, I use `s/[\r\n]*$//`

Comment: `chomp` removes whatever is specified as line break (`$/` variable). By default on OS X, I guess, it is set to something different than `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The carriage returns without linefeed are causing print to overwrite each line on the same line, so all you see is the last.

Run dos2unix on your input file before processing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to tell perl that your input file is windows-style :crlf.

`perldoc -f binmode` or `perldoc -f open`

`open(INFO, '<:crlf', './expensereport.csv')`
...

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, that's clear! :)

Look, you have a file with \r (carriage return, literally) and \n (newline). `chomp` cuts off \n (new line). So you print over the same line (remember "carriage return") again and again.

Use `print "$line\n";` instead

Comment: Even with that correction, it still prints the last line of the report.

Comment: I've just checked on a simple .CSV, and it does work. So likely your CSV has other, ehhm, peculiarities. Oh! Does your file actually contain '\n' ? Try to `hexdump -C expensereport.csv` and look for `0a` (usually after `0d`)